# How to inflate different fragments within the FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been programming for android for approximately seven weeks. I've started on a application that use the template "Tabs + Swipe", that was introduced in "IceCreamSandwich"(API level 14).

There are plenty question on stack-overflow concerning Fragments, but i haven't been able to find a solutions for my specific problem.

My problem is that the template "Tabs + Swipe" has 1 FragmentActivity which instantiate 3 tabs and the autogenerated onCreate method look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
    // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }

}
```

I want to make 3 fragments, 1 for each tab. How should i inflate my tab1.xml, tab2.xml and tab3.xml layout from the different fragments classes? Should i use the getItem method from the the class "PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter"?

```
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
       // pseudo-code explanation
       switch (i) {
       case 0:
            inflate tab1.xml;
       case 1:
            inflate tab2.xml;
       case 2:
           inflate tab3.xml;
       }
       return fragment;
    }
```

It's my first question here, so hope it's to understand.

Thanx Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the getItem() method should return the fragment. So it should look like this:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
       // pseudo-code explanation
       Fragment fragment;
       switch (i) {
       case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentTab1() // which inflates tab1.xml in its onCreateView() method;
       case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentTab2(); //etc.
       case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentTab3();
       }
       return fragment;
    }
```